# Better way to execute code in a Maven artifact directly? (no project)

Tags: java, maven

I really like the ability to be able to take a Maven artifact that has some useful code in it that can be run directly from the command line. You could run utilities directly from the command line or scripts without first having to download/install anything.

Right now I'm doing it like this inside a script:

```
mvn -q dependency:copy -Dartifact=${GROUPID}:${ARTIFACTID}:${VERSION}:pom -DoutputDirectory=${TARGET}
mvn -q dependency:copy -Dartifact=${GROUPID}:${ARTIFACTID}:${VERSION} -DoutputDirectory=${TARGET}
mvn -q dependency:copy-dependencies -f ${TARGET}/${ARTIFACTID}-${VERSION}.pom -DoutputDirectory=dependencies
java -cp ${TARGET}/\*:${TARGET}/dependencies/\* ${MAIN}
```

I tried doing it with the `exec` plugin, hoping that I could condense that into a single `mvn` call, but I wasn't able to get it to work.

Is there a better way to do this? (Like in a single `mvn` call)

Comment: I have my doubts that copying a packaging pom is something useful? Furthermore what kind of tools are you trying to run? Have they being built with Maven which looks like? Thought about using maven-assembly-plugin (jar-with-dependencies) or maven-shade-plugin ? And what has not worked with exec-maven-plugin?

Comment: Copying the packaging pom is needed for the other lines to work. And the tool I'm trying to run is irrelevant, it could be anything that has a `main()` method. The other methods you mention don't make this any easier, I'd still need to get the pom and I'd still need to execute using java. And finally the thing that didn't work with the exec-maven-plugin is that it seems that it doesn't retrieve dependencies, so I'd still need to do the copy-dependencies separately.